# how to remove all occurences of dot in a string in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

e.g hostname = "test.test.test", then after removing result should be like "testtesttest"

Answer (score 37):

```
$ foo=test.test.test
$ echo "${foo//./}"
testtesttest
```

Comment: Works nicely in Bourne-like shells. Not so good in tcsh `% tcsh -c 'foo=test.test.test; echo "${foo//./}"'
Missing }.`

Answer (score 28):

You can also pipe into

```
tr -d '.'
```

But the best way of doing this is not to use an external command and use shell built in.

Answer (score 15):

A general way would be to pipe it to sed:

```
sed -e 's/\.//g'
```

On command prompt:

```
$ echo $hostname                         // you type this
test.test.test                           // this is the result
$ echo $hostname | sed -e 's/\.//g'
testtesttest
```

Comment: @rupali: nope, you need to use `sed -e 's/ //g'` for that. I'd suggest you Google "sed tutorial" if you want to know more about sed's syntax. Just guessing how stuff works isn't enough; you have to understand it.

Comment: In shell script, I did like - <br>

hostname = "test test test" <br>
echo $hostname | sed -e 's/\ //g' <br>

using this, spaces are removed but I want that value should be updated in hostname <br>
so when I say - echo $hostname it should show me testtesttest <br>

Comment: @rupali: `echo $hostname | sed -e 's/ //g'` won't change hostname's variable, it will just print it out without spaces. If you want to really change `hostname` to `testtesttest`, then use `hostname testtesttest`, but be careful when doing that. Read [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-setting-default-values-for-shell-variables.html) and [this](http://ss64.com/bash/hostname.html).

Comment: well ...i dont need to set any hostname for the environment ...its just a normal string .... you can take for example ......... teststr = "test test test"  then next is, echo $teststr | sed -e 's/ //g' and now i want teststr = testesttest...tell me how to do it

Comment: you have written "If you want to really change hostname to testtesttest, then use hostname testtesttest.." I dont understand it

Comment: @rupali: Try this: `teststr = $(echo $teststr | sed -e 's/ //g')`

Answer (score 10):

Not just . but - and _ as well

```
HOSTNAME=test.test.test 
HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME//[-._]/} # testtesttest
```

Comment: i had to remove the last dash .